# Mysql stored proc: count bugs for all children tree for given parent

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am stuck at this issue.

I have 2 tables bugs and profiles

```
profiles table

id name parentid
1  A     0
2  B     1
3  C     1
4  D     2
5  E     2
6  F     3
7  G     5
```

and so on

bugs

```
id  assigned_to
1    1
2    3
4    7
```

and so on

assigned_to is foreign key for ID in profiles table

In single stored proc I need to display table that contains children for given parent and the count of bugs for those children's children tree

I was able to get to point where when i pass parent name i can create table of immidiate children but the count of bug is only for child and not for that child's tree

Please help

here is my code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`bugs`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_hier`(
in loginname varchar(255)
)
BEGIN

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;

create temporary table ProfileSum(
owner varchar(255),
ownerID smallint unsigned,
P0 smallint unsigned,
P1 smallint unsigned,
P2 smallint unsigned,
P3 smallint unsigned,
P4 smallint unsigned,
P5 smallint unsigned,
SP smallint unsigned,
Total smallint unsigned
)engine = memory;


create temporary table TotalBugByOwner(
owner varchar(255),
ownerID smallint unsigned,
P0 smallint unsigned,
P1 smallint unsigned,
P2 smallint unsigned,
P3 smallint unsigned,
P4 smallint unsigned,
P5 smallint unsigned,
SP smallint unsigned,
Total smallint unsigned,
depth smallint unsigned default 0
)engine = memory;

create temporary table hier(
parent_cat_id smallint unsigned, 
cat_id smallint unsigned,
loginemail varchar(255), 
depth smallint unsigned default 0
)engine = memory;

insert into ProfileSum
select
p.login_name ,
p.userid ,
count(case when b.priority = 'P0' then b.bug_id else NULL end) AS P0 ,
count(case when b.priority = 'P1' then b.bug_id else NULL end) AS P1 ,
count(case when b.priority = 'P2' then b.bug_id else NULL end) AS P2 ,
count(case when b.priority = 'P3' then b.bug_id else NULL end) AS P3 ,
count(case when b.priority = 'P4' then b.bug_id else NULL end) AS P4 ,
count(case when b.priority = 'P5' then b.bug_id else NULL end) AS P5 ,
count(case when b.priority = 'Set Priority' then b.bug_id else NULL end) AS SetPriority ,
sum(case when b.priority in ('P0' , 'P1' , 'P2' , 'P3' , 'P4' , 'P5' , 'Set Priority') then 1 else NULL end) AS Total
from bugs b
right outer join profiles p on b.assigned_to = p.userid 
group by p.login_name ;

insert into hier select MgrID, userid, login_name, v_depth from profiles where login_name = loginname;
create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

if exists( select 1 from profiles p
    inner join tmp on p.MgrID = tmp.cat_id and tmp.depth = v_depth) then

    insert into hier select p.MgrID, p.userid, p.login_name, v_depth + 1 from profiles p
        inner join tmp on p.MgrID = tmp.cat_id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

    set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

    truncate table tmp;
    insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

else
    set v_done = 1;
end if;

end while;

insert into TotalBugByOwner
select
PS.owner,
PS.ownerID ,
sum(PS.P0) As P0,
sum(PS.P1) As P1,
sum(PS.P2) As P2,
sum(PS.P3) As P3,
sum(PS.P4) As P4,
sum(PS.P5) As P5,
sum(PS.SP) As SetPriority,
sum(PS.Total) As Total,
h.depth
from ProfileSum PS
JOIN hier h on PS.ownerID = h.cat_id
group by PS.owner;

select * from TotalBugByOwner;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists ProfileSum;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;
drop temporary table if exists totalbugbyowner;

END
```